# "Project->Project Options" is disabled/greyed out in Xamarin

Tags: windows, xamarin-studio

I'm on Xamarin Studio 6.0.2 (Build 73), running on Windows. Even when I create a fresh new project, the Project Options menu entry is disabled, which means I have to edit the .csproj file in Notepad++, which is not very convenient.

Some other menu entries are also greyed out. As I said, this happens even for New projects created by Xamarin Studio.

[image]

Comment: Have you installed Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS too? These are bundled in the Xamarin.VisualStudio installer - even if you are only using Xamarin Studio you need to install this.

Comment: @BytesGuy How do I check if they are? There is a `"c:\Program Files (x86)\Xamarin Studio\AddIns\Xamarin.Forms.Addin\Templates\iOS"` and `"c:\Program Files (x86)\Xamarin Studio\AddIns\Xamarin.Forms.Addin\Templates\Android"`, so maybe they are installed but I'm not sure.

Comment: `Help -> About -> Show Details -> Copy Information` - paste it into a gist. I have a feeling this issue may just be caused by not having Xamarin.Android installed.

Comment: @BytesGuy http://pastebin.com/C13mfB9A. Xamarin.Android is not installed it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So having looked at your version information it seems like Xamarin.Android is not installed which is why you are having this issue.

You will need to install the Xamarin.VisualStudio package. Even if you only intend to use Xamarin Studio, this is required as it includes both Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS.

Please reach out to contact@xamarin.com and we can provide you with the link for this! Please add the link to this question in your email.

Comment: Thanks. Just to be sure - I didn't specify it but I'm using Xamarin Studio for a Windows C# project. This project is not an Android or iOS app, it's a Windows application, I even use the Windows .NET framework (Xamarin Studio has an option for this), so I was a bit surprised that those packages would be needed. I had tagged this Xamarin initially because I didn't realise there is a difference between Xamarin and Xamarin Studio, I didn't know there is a Visual Studio package for Xamarin at all.

Comment: Xamarin Studio for Windows will allow you to develop Android projects only. Your best option for Windows C# projects is Visual Studio. If you are eligible you can use Visual Studio Community Edition here - https://www.visualstudio.com/post-download-vs?sku=community&clcid=0x409&downloadrename=true (licence agreement for eligibility here - https://www.visualstudio.com/support/legal/mt171547)